# Is it possible to specify storage class with azcopy?

Tags: azure, storage, cloud-storage

I would like to use azcopy to sync a local drive with cloud storage. However I want to specify it to use archive storage tier. Is this possible? I am not really clear from the help page:

```
$ ./azcopy.exe --help
AzCopy 10.16.1
Project URL: github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy

AzCopy is a command line tool that moves data into and out of Azure Storage.
To report issues or to learn more about the tool, go to github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy

The general format of the commands is: 'azcopy [command] [arguments] --[flag-name]=[flag-value]'.

Usage:
  azcopy [command]

Available Commands:
  bench          Performs a performance benchmark
  completion     Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  copy           Copies source data to a destination location
  doc            Generates documentation for the tool in Markdown format
  env            Shows the environment variables that you can use to configure the behavior of AzCopy.
  help           Help about any command
  jobs           Sub-commands related to managing jobs
  list           List the entities in a given resource
  login          Log in to Azure Active Directory (AD) to access Azure Storage resources.
  logout         Log out to terminate access to Azure Storage resources.
  make           Create a container or file share.
  remove         Delete blobs or files from an Azure storage account
  set-properties (Preview) Given a location, change all the valid system properties of that storage (blob or file)
  sync           Replicate source to the destination location

Flags:
      --cap-mbps float                      Caps the transfer rate, in megabits per second. Moment-by-moment throughput might vary slightly from the cap. If this option is set to zero, or it is omitted, the throughput isn't capped.
  -h, --help                                help for azcopy
      --log-level string                    Define the log verbosity for the log file, available levels: INFO(all requests/responses), WARNING(slow responses), ERROR(only failed requests), and NONE(no output logs). (default 'INFO'). (default "INFO")
      --output-level string                 Define the output verbosity. Available levels: essential, quiet. (default "default")
      --output-type string                  Format of the command's output. The choices include: text, json. The default value is 'text'. (default "text")
      --trusted-microsoft-suffixes string   Specifies additional domain suffixes where Azure Active Directory login tokens may be sent.  The default is '*.core.windows.net;*.core.chinacloudapi.cn;*.core.cloudapi.de;*.core.usgovcloudapi.net;*.storage.azure.net'. Any listed here are added to the default. For security, you should only put Microsoft Azure domains here. Separate multiple entries with semi-colons.
  -v, --version                             version for azcopy

Use "azcopy [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
--block-blob-tier='Archive'
```

in the AzCopy command. For more info on the actual copy command, run

```
AzCopy Copy ?
```